# React Native - IOS In App Purchase webview

Tags: ios, react-native, uiwebview, in-app-purchase, app-store

I'm using react-native to build an app for my website(webview).
Payment method is already available in the website.
App store rejected my app for not using In-App-Purchase.

What should I do to make use of the payment method in my website using IAP.

How can I publish this app(Webview) using IAP ?
Please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: You can't use in app purchase in a web view. You need to handle it in your app, either in native code or react code that wraps native code

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for your time.
Can you please tell me how to handle it on react native?